# Page only posts back with Fiddler attached?

Tags: asp.net, iis, forms-authentication, postback, fiddler

I have Reporting Services set up with Forms Authentication. Our app is sitting over Reporting Services and uses it's authentication extension as a Single Sign On.

We have a simple logon page that we've got working in the past but on this one machine it refuses to post back when the logon button is clicked. I have Trace information inserted into the page using:

```
<%@ Page language="c#" Debug="True" Trace="True" Codebehind="UILogon.aspx.cs" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="CustomAuthExtension.UILogon, CustomAuthExtension" Culture="auto" meta:resourcekey="PageResource1" UICulture="auto" %>
```

I can see the session ID change on every button click. If I attach to process I see it go through InitComponent but it never hits the btnLogon_click code.

However, if I run fiddler all is well and it posts back fine.

What is going on? Timeout? IIS settings incorrect?

**Edit:** IE7 (app is IE only) and I've just figured out that if I leave it on the breakpoint in OnInit for a couple of seconds it will work and hit the second breakpoint in btnLogon_Click, if I let it go straight away it doesn't hit it. Which points to some sort of weird timeout issue.

Comment: IE7 from any machine... app is IE only (please don't hurt me! It was like that when I got here!). I've just figured out that if I hold it on the breakpoint in OnInit for a couple of seconds it works fine. If I let it go straight away I see the same result... weird

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a configuration issue with IIS. Should never have anonymous and windows auth enabled for the Reporting Services forms extension to work correctly with an external app.

Reran our set up process and it works now.